# Is it possible to use Linq-to-SQL with nhibernate envers?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql, nhibernate-envers

Is there a way to use Linq-to-SQL with nhibernate envers to query through revisions without having to use envers audit expressions?

I would like to avoid using something like this, which requires hardcoded string property names:

> reader.CreateQuery()
>                   .ForEntitiesAtRevision(1)
>                   .Add(AuditEntity.Property("FirstName").Eq("bob"))
>                   .Results();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only built in query api is the "criteria like" you mention.